# Ok to add <script> tag *before* <head> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I know most of you will be thinking "why would you want to do that"? Basically I have a CMS system that caches entire page outputs, so I can't include this specific item inside `<head>` or `<body>` because I don't want it to get cached.

I have tried it successfully in chrome, firefox, safari and Opera. In fact, these browsers all seem to automatically move it into the `<head>` on page render. I just wanted to know if there was any other reason why I should avoid this.

Comment: Try in IE 6. (You will be lucky if the computer is still useable afterwards.)

Comment: No, it's not OK. But yes, actually, it is OK.

Comment: Interesting why people see the need to vote down this question. It's a perfectly legit question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no particular reason to not do this, if you really need to. Browsers are amazingly resilient in the face of all kinds of weird markup. For instance, browsers will handle `<style>` tags anywhere at all, even though in theory they should go in the `<head>`.

Having said that, you can not be sure that something, sometime, somewhere, will not break in some unpleasant way.

But isn't there an alternative, such as including a separate `<script src=` tag in the cached HTML, which will be handled separately by the server and serve up the dynamic JS that it seems you don't want to cache?

Comment: Thanks, this is the kinda answer I was looking for from someone reading the full question. It's actually only for some optional ?diagnostics included from server, that I don't want to add inside ```<head>``` because diagnostics output would get cached. The injection only happens when appending ```?diagnostics``` in URL anyway, any validation and political correctness is not a consideration.

I could perhaps do as you suggested, but that would include loading another resource, even if it was empty.

Answer (score 1):

Placing something outside of `head` or `body` is simply not correct HTML.

`html` tag content model is:

> A head element followed by a body element

See http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html#the-html-element.

Comment: Right. But the question was actually not, will my page pass validation, but was actually, will doing this work and not cause some horrific problem?

Comment: @torazaburo The OP wants "any other reason why I should avoid this." as far as I understand it.

Comment: Sure, I guess not being conformant is a theoretical reason to avoid it. I think the OP already knows it's not conformant, which is why he posted his question. I sort of interpreted his question as being are there **practical** reasons to avoid it, like some scenario where it won't work.

Comment: I didn't ask if it was semantic, or if it was "correct". I know where to put the tags if I have the choice, but here I had to find a workaround on how to include variable data into the document without affecting anything between ```<head></head>``` which is cached. The injected script is only for diagnostics reasons anyway when using ?diagnostics in the URL, and is not something that will see it's way in the public URL.